# Basemap ImportError on Jupyter Notebook (using macOS)

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I have error on Jupyter Notebook with macOS as below

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in
>
> ----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

seems have problem on installing Basemap.  So I tried,

(1) **!conda install -c anaconda basemap -y**
: installed successfully according to message.  And closed all browser and restarted but still have ImportError.

(2) Installed anaconda and tried to install basemap from "Environments" tab by select basemap from "Not Installed" list, check and apply.
But I have another error as below

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
> to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
> - basemap -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
>
> Your python: python=3.8
>
> If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
> When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
> not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
> change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
> that.

But my python version is 3.9.5

How can I install Basemap to avoid ImportError?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by running follow line on Jupyter

> conda install -c conda-forge basemap matplotlib==3.1 -y